# IOS - Saving NSDictionary to Disk

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have a NSDictionary, which contains a bunch of arrays that have NSDates for keys, each array contains a variable amount of NSStrings

Something like this:

```
NSDictionary

Key: 1999-whatever-whatever
Object: (Array)
   "Some string"
   "Some other string"

Key: 2000-whatever-whatever
Object: (Array)
    "Some third string"
```

I have been looking in to writeToFile, but it does not seem to support NSDictionarys that have NSDates for keys, so i looked in to KeydArchiver, would this be the best aproach?

If it is, any tutorial on the topic would be helpfull.

Thanks for your time.

PS: I assume i should do the save on ApplicationWillTerminate?

Comment: If these are for user preferences you should use `NSUserDefaults` instead... You can use `NSKeyedArchiver` for any class that implements the `NSCoding` protocol, but it won't be human readable. If you want human-readable, consider using `NSJSONSerialization` or `NSXMLWriter`

Comment: You will have to convert your keys into property list types before you serialize your dictionary--`NSKeyedArchiver` also won't work, I tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** -- I didnt realize your question said iOS. So disregard the way i saved the dictionary to your desktop, but the method for saving the NSDate as string is the same.

You don't have to go into KeydArchiver if you change the way you save your NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary

Key: 1999-08-13    //<----- Have this as a string in your dictionary. Not NSDate
Object: (Array)
   "Some string"
   "Some other string"

Key: 2000-08-13    //<------Have this as a string in your dictionary. Not NSDate
Object: (Array)
    "Some third string"
```

When you want to save the NSDictionary to a file you can do it like so:

```
[MyDictionary writeToFile:@"/Users/yourUsername/Desktop/mySavedDictionary.plist" atomically:YES];
```

If you want to load the dictionary again:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/yourUsername/Desktop/mySavedDictionary.plist"];
```

After loading your dictionary, lets say you want to get the data stored at the date 2000-08-13, then you can do it like so:

First im making the assumption that the NSDate `myPreviouslyDeclaredDate` is the date you want to look up in the dictionary and that its in the format yyyy-MM-dd. You can choose what ever format you want however. Use the [AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) as a guide.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *previouslyDeclaredDateInStringForm = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myPreviouslyDeclaredDate];
id objectNeededFromDictionary = [myDictionary objectForKey:previouslyDeclaredDateInStringForm];
```

Comment: Thanks for the very complete response

Comment: np. Always check the simple before the more complicated ;)

Answer (score 2):

`writeToFile` only works with basic types. I've done this once creating a new dictionary where the keys are `NSStrings` and then using `writeToFile`. It is obvious that I have to have a method to convert the strings into my original key format when reading from the file.

Comment: I think it's more correct to say NSDictionary serialization only accepts Property List types for it's key types. You can serialize complex types that support NSCoding in the values.

Comment: I agree it is "more correct" to say this things about serialization and NSCoding stuff but I tried to explain in a way that I would like to hear if I was a begginner in the subject. Anyway, I should have provided simple and complete explanations.